# Adding Canvas in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-framelayout

I don't know why I am getting this error
I need Help. Thanks in advance.

**LOGCAT**

- 01-04 05:02:37.392: E/AndroidRuntime(3186): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.frame/com.example.frame.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.example.frame.Map

**ACTIVITY**

```
package com.example.frame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Map map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = (Map)findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MAP**

```
package com.example.frame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class Map extends View {
    Paint paint;

    public Map(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public Map(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Map(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(2000, 2000, 5000, 5000, paint);
    }
}
```

**LAYOUT**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.frame.Map
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override remaining Constructors of `View` also which takes `AttributeSet` as parameter as you are defining `Map View` in xml...

```
    public class Map extends View {

        public Map(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public Map(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public Map(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
    }
```

and replace

```
 map = new Map(this);
```

line in `Activity` with

```
 map = (Map)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

Comment: Thanks sir but i edited my code as u said but still i am facing problem please help. You may see my edited code.. :(

Comment: @user3148422 initialize Paint variable...

Paint paint = new Paint();